# The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified

Tags: sql, view

```
use library
go

create view V_booksOut3
as
SELECT
(select Book.Book_Title from Book where LB.B_ID=Book.Book_ID) as 'Book_Title',
L.Loaner_FName,
L.Loaner_Lname,
L.Loaner_Phone,
L.Loaner_Email,`enter code here`
LB.bookDueDate
FROM Loaner L
inner join Loaner_Book LB
ON L.Loaner_ID=LB.L_ID
WHERE LB.isActive = 1
ORDER BY L.Loaner_LName;
```

--I keep running into this error, but it fades once I remove the last to lines and try to create a view.
I do not wish to use the top/for xml keywords, but I want this view created with this query.

Comment: I have seen similar questions on this site, but I am unable to make out what is wrong with my query.

Comment: Remove `Order By` from `View` definition and use it when selecting the `View`. `Select * from V_booksOut3 Order by Loaner_LName`

Comment: @Prdp
Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets, unless an `ORDER BY` is explicitly included.  This includes subqueries as well.  So, the results from a subquery are *unordered* -- they have to be.  It simply does not make sense to have an `ORDER BY`.

Some databases relax this restriction.  However, SQL Server is quite [explicit about it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx):

> The SELECT clauses in a view definition cannot include the following:
>
> - An ORDER BY clause, unless there is also a TOP clause in the select
>     list of the SELECT statement System_CAPS_ICON_important.jpg Important
>
> **The ORDER BY clause is used only to determine the rows that are
>   returned by the TOP or OFFSET clause in the view definition. The ORDER
>   BY clause does not guarantee ordered results when the view is queried,
>   unless ORDER BY is also specified in the query itself.**

Answer (score 0):

Please remove Order by clause from inner query and put it outside or you've to have Top clause in Inner query. you will surely got your solution,  happy sql bro :)

actually when you created view, you can use that in query, so if u can use this in query then you surely apply order by on created view, means view will be created as raw table without order by, then you apply order by clause on that created dataset view.

Hope it will clear confusion.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.